# Powershell - command line app throws exception relating to 64-bit although PS is 64-bit?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I've developed a commandline interface to an external API in c#. This works fine stand-alone running from cmd and bat files. I would like to use Powershell to create a script. However, it fails with the error below. Why does it complain about only being able to run from 64-bit although the PS process is 64-bit?

```
=== RM Tool - Remetrica Command Line Interface ===
RMTool.exe : 
At X:\Activities\2022\Remetrica Automation\prod_test_rmtool.ps1:1 char:1
+ & rmtool.exe sample -r "X:/Activities/2022/Remetrica Automation/RM/20 ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
Unhandled Exception: 
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Aon.ReMetrica.Framework.Api.ReMetrica' threw an exception. ---> System.BadImageFormatException: The ReMetrica API can only be us
ed in a 64 bit process.
   at Aon.ReMetrica.Framework.Api.ReMetrica..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Aon.ReMetrica.Framework.Api.ReMetrica.get_Study()
   at RemetricaController.RMTool.ExexSampleAndReturnExitCode(SamplePropertyOptions opts, TextWriter infoWriter, StreamWriter logWriter) in X:\Activities\2022\Remetrica Automation\RMTool\RMTo
ol.cs:line 208
   at RemetricaController.RMTool.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<Main>b__0(SamplePropertyOptions opts) in X:\Activities\2022\Remetrica Automation\RMTool\RMTool.cs:line 131
   at CommandLine.ParserResultExtensions.MapResult[T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,TResult](ParserResult`1 result, Func`2 parsedFunc1, Func`2 parsedFunc2, Func`2 parsedFunc3, Func`2 parsedFunc4, Func`2 parse
dFunc5, Func`2 notParsedFunc)
   at RemetricaController.RMTool.Main(String[] args) in X:\Activities\2022\Remetrica Automation\RMTool\RMTool.cs:line 128

PS C:\Windows\system32> [Environment]::Is64BitProcess
True'''
```

Comment: Did you compile your C# project as AnyCPU? Try to compile it explicitly as x64 since you have a dependency which requires 64-bit anyway.

Comment: Yes, it was compiled as AnyCPU and changing to x64 solved the issue. Thank you!